# Finding smallest element of list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested-loops

I tried the following code, and the results are given below that. I know of other methods, but I'd like to know why this one fails.

```
l=list(input("Enter a list:"))

for a in l:
    for b in l:
        if a>=b:
            break
        else:
            print(a,l.index(a))
```

Result:

Enter a list:3,2,4,5
, 1
2 2
, 1
, 1

Comment: Every single character in your input including spaces and commas will be an item of the list if you cast it like that.

Answer (score -1):

Replace first line with this:

```
l=eval("["+input("Enter a list:")+"]")
```

Comment: Using `.split(',')` on your input is a **much** better solution than `eval()`.

Comment: @Klaus Sure. Is that because eval might think it's not a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice